# python: importing a file that is not a valid identifier?

Tags: python, import, python-2.7

I have a script "7update.py" and would like to import it. Is there any way to do this? I can't just type `import 7update` because it starts with a number so it's not a valid identifier. I've tried using `import('7update')` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number) -- well, it's "8puzzle" instead of "7update"..

Comment: Learnt something thanks to your question, +1.

Comment: Why would you be in such a situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
seven_up = __import__("7update")
```

Where `seven_up` is valid identifier you're going to be using in your python code for that module.

Answer (score 4):

You can, but you have to refer to it by a valid identifier, like that:

```
__import__('7update')
sevenupdate = sys.modules['7update']
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an example from the docs:](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#examples)

```
import imp
import sys

def __import__(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=None):
    # Fast path: see if the module has already been imported.
    try:
        return sys.modules[name]
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # If any of the following calls raises an exception,
    # there's a problem we can't handle -- let the caller handle it.

    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)

    try:
        return imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
    finally:
        # Since we may exit via an exception, close fp explicitly.
        if fp:
            fp.close()
```