# Python module names starting with numerals

Tags: python, python-2.7, naming-conventions

When I try to import a module in python(.py file) it gives a syntax error. The module name starts with a numeral. Is that the reason for the syntax error?

Comment: Your question is already solved here. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number) You can do `theModule = __import__('123theModuleName')` here instead of `import 123theModuleName` And, you should not import modules including the suffix ".py" as well, but I guess you already knew that.

Comment: I tried the above code but it still says "NameError: name '_import_' is not defined".

Comment: You should add two underscores on both side of `import`, thus made it `__import__`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is the reason for the syntax error. There are various ways of importing it anyway, but it's better to rename the module.

The reason is that variable names can't start with a numeral. Hence you can't do

```
import 123foo
```

or even

```
123foo = __import__('123foo')
```

They are both syntax errors. You can do

```
foo123 = __import__('123foo')
```

But it's better to just rename the module to foo123 and import it normally instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. To avoid this, you can do `__import__("number")`. For example:

```
mymodule = __import__("1234")
```

Which would be the same as:

```
import 1234 as mymodule
```

Without the `SyntaxError`, of course.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number).

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should. ;-)

Comment: @LennartRegebro True :).