# Python3 import file from directory starting with number

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I tried the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number) to no avail so I thought it'd be worth a separate question. The directory layout is as follows:

```
aale/
     2/
       2.py
       __init__.py
     3/
       3.py
       __init__.py
     __init__.py
```

The names are unfortunately unable to change (this is the layout given to us for a HW problem). I am trying to import `2` from `3` but it doesn't seem to be working. I tried using `importlib` as:

`two = importlib.import_module('2.2')` as well as
`two = importlib.import_module('2')`

which didn't work also (gave a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '2'` error). Any help / other methods would be appreciated. I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: What is the error when you use the accepted answer to your linked question?

Comment: @roganjosh same `ModuleNotFound` error, I think `import_module` is a wrapper for `__import__` anyway

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: @MosheSlavin I'm just using sublime to edit and running the program on the command line with `python3 3.py`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In python, how to import filename starts with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__), i.e.:

```
two  = __import__("2.2") # or __import__("aale.2.2") 
three = __import__("3.3") # or __import__("aale.3.3")
```

Equivalent to:

```
import 2.2 as two  
import 3.3 as three
```

which isn't possible.

---

**Notes:**

1. According to `PEP 8 styling guide`:

   > **Package** and **Module Names** should have **short, all-lowercase names**.   Underscores can be used in the module name
   > if it improves
   > readability.
2. I've tested the imports using the same folder structure as in your
   question and no errors were shown.

---

**References:**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16644280/797495
2. [In python, how to import filename starts with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number)
3. [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Well, ok, but this is an assignment for the OP and this does not fix the issue

Comment: @AJwr I didn't realize it was HW, answer updated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your script is in the `aale` directory, you will need to do your import like:

```
two = importlib.import_module('aale.2.2')
```

Comment: for this I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aale'`

Comment: I don't know what to say to that, I just tested your exact structure.  Although you do state you have `__init.__py`, which should be `__init__.py`

Comment: yeah just a typo. hmm, well we might be out of luck then

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib`

It is basic:

```
from pathlib import Path


BASE_LOCATION = Path(__file__).parent
```

(You can add `.parent` to get to the folder above and so on.)

**Edit**

If this doesn't help you, you can try `import weirdimport`.

You can read more about this [here](https://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-init-py-trap).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure as to how to use this. Should I be using `importlib` on the path I get from this?

Comment: In @Stephen's answer, you said you get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aale'` so in addition to his solution you can add the path from pathlib