# Can a Python package name start with a number?

Tags: python

I know that naming a Python module starting with a number is a bad idea, as stated in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number), but I'm wondering if is it legal to do so in a Python package, not module (aka file).

For example. I want to integrate a Django website with some external APIs and I wanted to create a "third party" package, containing a file for each provider, and I don't know if calling it `3rd_party` will become a headache or I should name it `third_party` instead, to avoid problems.

*Note: I don't know if it matters, but I'm using Python 2.7*

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, it cannot. Python package and module names need to be [valid identifiers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers):

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
```

Identifiers *must* start with a letter or an underscore.

The [import statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-module) defines the grammar for modules as:

```
module          ::=  (identifier ".")* identifier
```

Packages are a special kind of module (implemented as a directory with `__init__.py` file) and are not exempt from these rules.

*Technically* you can work around this by not using the `import` statement, as the `importlib` module and `__import__` hook do not enforce the restriction. It is however not a good idea to name your package or module such that you need to use non-standard import mechanisms to make it work.

Comment: I'm asking about packages, not modules.

Comment: packages are specialized modules implemented as directories, so the rules still apply.

Comment: OK, so packages, as well as modules can't start with a number. So, I'll go with `third_party`. Thanks! :)

Comment: I completelly agree with you that using a "hack" is not the way to go!

Comment: it means, I can not have a "-" in my package right?

Comment: @SahithVibudhi right. A dash is not in the list. Letters, underscores and if it isn’t the first character, digits, only.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

```
# 1/x.py dont forget 1/__init__.py
x = 42
```

Import it from another file

```
# test.py
p1 = __import__('1.x')
print p1.x.x
```

Comment: In your example `1.py` is a Python module, not a package.

Comment: Requiring a work-around doesn't make a module that useful by others.

Comment: I agree with @MartijnPieters, I'll accept his answer as it perfectly explained the case and solved my doubt. Thanks!

Comment: @Caumons Sorry. A similar approach works for a package. I also agree with MartijnPieters. This is just a toy, should not appear in any production.