# Python Import function from file

Tags: python, import

I have a function ispalindrome in  file named  `8.py` how to import it ?
      why 8 is invalid name if I can make a .py file with this name

```
from 8 import ispalindrome
```

Comment: This should work in general. Any failure maybe?

Comment: rename the file from 8 to something else!

Comment: `8`is not a valid name for a Python module. They need to start with an underscore or letter. Fix that, and you'll be good.

Comment: I believe this was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best answer: rename your file. ;)

Having a file named `8.py` breaks the [naming convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for files as well as Python's [language grammar](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) (your trouble importing it makes it clear why these rules are in place).

Generally, you should make filenames the same as variables:

1. They start with a letter or underscore.
2. After that, they are composed entirely of letters, numbers, and underscores.
3. They are lowercase.
4. They are short (nobody likes a huge name to import).

---

However, if you *must* name the file `8.py`, you can use [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#__import__) to import it.

To demonstrate, I made a simple `8.py` file that had the following function:

```
def func():
    return True
```

Here is the test I ran:

```
>>> from 8 import func
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from 8 import func
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> x = __import__("8")
>>> x.func()
True
>>>
```

As you can see, using `__import__` *works*.  However, it is considered sloppy and should generally be avoided.  I strongly recommended that you heed my first answer and rename the file if you can.

Comment: +1 for the first part.

Comment: Yes, and downvote for even mentioning the second part to a novice user.

Comment: Well, removed the downvote after you added the disclaimer. Still, the topic here should be naming rules (why is `8` an invalid name?), not import trickery.

Comment: @LukasGraf - There.  I added a huge disclaimer and also linked to the PEP docs. I gave the newbie all of the bubblewrap I could. :)

Comment: @iCodez Much better. However, identifiers not starting with a number is not just a convention encouraged by PEP8, it's a requirement defined in the [lanuage grammar](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). So by absuing `__import__` to still import such a module is something that just shouldn't be done, even by someone who knows what he's doing. `__import__` has its legitimate uses (dynamically importing modules by name for example), but this is not one of them in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Python module names have to be valid identifiers. "8" is not a valid identifier. Try "eight" or "file8" or anything that does not start with a number.

Comment: +1 for not poisoning young minds with `__import__`