# Creating alias of long imports in python

Tags: python, python-import

[image]

I want to avoid a long import like this:

```
from a.b.c.d.e import 1
from a.b.c.d.e import 2
```

Is it possible to create an alias of a.b.c.d.e ? or can we make it shorter ?

I have tried something which is not working:

```
 import a.b.c.d.e as x
 import x.1
 import x.2
```

Comment: How has that become necessary? Why don't the intermediate `__init__.py`s aggregate some of the sub-modules?

Comment: `a.b.c.d.e` doesn't lead to an actual python module. `a.b.c.d.e.1` does. In that case you can say `import a.b.c.d.e.1 as x1`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't start your modules names from digits (although [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number) exists).

Next, (assuming 1.py, 2.py, 3.py are renamed to m1.py, m2.py, m3.py) approach

```
import a.b.c.d.e as x
m1 = x.m1
m2 = x.m2
```

works fine.

Also, as by jonrsharpe's comment, you'd better aggregate sub-modules imports in corresponding `__init__.py` files.