# Use program to input in a different program?

Tags: python, input

I am kind of new in programming (I only know python). Yesterday I finished making a 2048 game (running in the command line). Now I decided to make an AI that would auto-play, but I don't want this AI to run each time I run the game.

So to my question, is there a way to make a program/script to actually input (in the command line) and read data from another program?

My "move" code from my 2048 game:

```
def move():
    global board
    direction = "x"
    while direction != "a" and direction != "w" and direction != "s" and direction != "d":
          direction = raw_input("Where do you want to move?(WASD)")
          direction = direction.lower()
          if direction == "a":
             left()
          elif direction == "w":
             up()
          elif direction == "s":
             down()
          elif direction == "d":
             right()
```

So what I want is a second program that is actually inputting in the( direction = raw_input("Where do you want to move?(WASD)")) instead of the player.

Is there a way to do this?
Edit:
    I am running windows 10

Comment: Which operating system are you running?

Comment: You could pipe the output from the other program into it.

Comment: @kylek I am actually a newbie(programming for about a month and a half) so if you could be a bit more specific

Comment: You could also just have the AI write the move to a text file and then read that file from your 2048 code to retrieve it.

Comment: @Feconiz if you are using a unix system then you can redirect the output from one program to another using the pipe character like this `./script1.py | ./script2.py` that will feed each line of the output from script 1 into script 2, so each call of raw_input will read a line from the output of the other script.

Comment: could you please be a bit more specific ?how would I do that ? @kylek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the call for `raw_input` to call you custom function that handles the input.

Something like:

```
from my_other_script import get_input

def move():
    global board
    direction = "x"
    while direction != "a" and direction != "w" and direction != "s" and direction != "d":
          direction = get_input(board)
          if direction == "a":
             left()
          elif direction == "w":
             up()
          elif direction == "s":
             down()
          elif direction == "d":
             right()
```

And in *my_other_script.py* have a function named `get_input` that does whatever you want to generate the input

```
def get_input(board):
    # my conditions go here
    return direction
```

Note that I'm passing the `board` so you can know what is current board state and use it to choose the best move.

If you CAN'T replace the `raw_input` call, you can [monkey patch it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) using the [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) module.

Comment: Thank you :) I hadn't thought of that

Comment: hmmm that doesn't seem to work...have i done something wrong ? (both files are in the same folder)    from 2048_Ai.py import get_input (it throws invalid syntax)

Comment: drop the `.py`, just use `from 2048_Ai import get_input`

Comment: actually the 2048 messed it up even after removing the .py.....so now its just named Ai :) thanks

Comment: Oh yeah, python doesn't allow variables to start with numbers (and import is the same as setting them with a variable name), check this answer on how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number

Answer (score 0):

No this would be very tough and compilicated.

I would recommend incorporating the AI into you're script, and then giving the user the option of playing as either him/herself or allowing the AI to play:

```
print "Would you like to play, or watch the AI play?"
print " 1) User"
print " 2) AI "
userOrAI = raw_input("")
if (userOrAI == "1"):
    move()
if (userOrAI == "2"):
    AImove() #you would need to create a function to play as AI here
else:
   print "Invalid entry"
```

Comment: yes i could do that also ,now that you mentioned it i can see how silly is my question.....thanks