# python file import another python file, prompts error

Tags: python, file, syntax, import, execute

I'm on mac using python2.7 and I have 2 python files under same directory

```
$ls *.py
1p.py 2.py
```

And they're very simple:

```
$cat 1p.py
def f():
    print "hello"

$cat 2.py
import 1p
f()
```

But running 2.py failed:

```
$python 2.py
File "2.py", line 1
    import 1p
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do I need to setup and env variable, or to change my program?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In python, how to import filename starts with a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be imported, module names, and thus file names must be valid python identifiers. So even if your filesystem accepts the name, it's not enough.

An identifier like `1p` isn't valid, you have to rename your module file. Why not `p1.py` instead? That would work.