# Python Import everything from multiple file module into namespace

Tags: python, python-module

Let's say I have this:

```py
script.py
module/
    __init__.py # just contains: __all__ = ['foo', 'bar']
    foo.py      # has a function called foo
    bar.py      # has a function called bar
```

If from `script.py` I do `from module import *` it works, but to call the foo or bar function I have to do `foo.foo() / bar.bar()`.

Is there any way to have the foo and bar functions in the namespace, so I could call them by just doing `foo() / bar()` ?

Edit: The accepted answer works for this example case, but upon testing it doesn't seem to work if a file has a number in it's name.

For example, if you add a file named `bar2.py` with an function called hello to the module folder, and edit the `__init__.py` accordingly, then in the `script.py` you arent't be able to call the hello function directly (by just doing `hello()`) on the script, though you can do `bar2.hello()`, which works but isn't exactly what I want.

Edit: After a lot of testing I have found that by removing the __all__ and just keeping the imports it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `__init__.py`, write these two import statements:

```
from .foo import foo
from .bar import bar
```

Edit: if your module name have numbers in it.

```
from foo2 import foo
from bar2 import bar
```

Comment: I'd agree - but I'm not sure about the . e.g. .foo

Comment: What is that you are not sure of? ".foo" in "from" statement?

Comment: Yes - it works. But it's not a practice I've come across before. Normally I'd use "from foo import foo" or "from foo import *" without a '.'

Comment: @ShaneGannon it's because they are in the same path. This is a relative import. Very useful when you have a lot of sub directories or to make sure it won't import from global installed packages

Comment: This works well, except when a file (in the case of the example, either the foo.py or the bar.py) has a number on their name, which is my case.

Comment: @matdumb have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number - it should work for you

Comment: Even after trying that, I still get the same error. To be clear, the digit isn't the first character, It can be manually imported

Comment: @matdumb: edit your question or create a new question with the error. So the community can help you.