# Python:How do I access function from a class from another module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

So, I have a project structure like following.

```
Project
   |
   |--- Module1
          |----- __init__.py 
          |----- A.py
          |----- 1B.py
                   |---- update()
   |--- Module2
          |----- __init__.py 
          |----- C.py
          |----- D.py
   |--- Tests
          |----- Test1.py
```

I am very new to modular structure in python. So all the examples I have seen, have **init**.py as an empty file. I suppose it needs to be there to make Module1 as `module`.

I am trying to import `A.py` in `Test1.py`

`1B.py` has a class `B` which has a method `update(self,x)`. The `1B.py` filename is intentional because I want to know how to import file starting with a number and file starting with letter.

How can import `1B.py` which is from `Module1` and then use `update` method

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"../")

class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_update(self):
        target = __import__("Module1.1B",fromlist=[])
        print(target.Solution)
```

- I tried `from Module1.1B ...` which throws error hence I used **import** 
  where I get `<module 'Module1' from '..\\Module1\\__init__.py'>` when I print `target`
- Does this mean that I was successful to access module `Module1`?
- Also to make this work, I added sys.path.insert to the path so that it can refer to the parent folder.
- What I am trying to do is that I will have a dedicated test function for every class or function in my test file.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use [import_lib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) rather than `__import__`. As specified by the documentation, you can specify the name argument in absolute or relative terms.

Also, you shouldn't need to use `sys.path.insert`: just call your test script using `python -m pkg.script_name` (omit the `.py`).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your package is in the same directory where you will be calling your main function you can import that class, create an instance of it, then call the method. Also your directories which contain **init** files are called packages, your individual files such as A and 1B are known as modules.

```py
   from Module1 import 1B.B
   bclass = B()
   bclass.update()
```

Additionally your **init**.py files should import the modules you want as  well

```py
   import Module1.A
   import Module1.1B
```

Comment: Ohh, I see. I messed up with the terminology. Also, import won't work in the case of the file starting with a number. according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number) I have to use __import__. Further I shoulf use importlib than using __import__, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38813946/3786108)

Comment: So, I found the answer to this. I had to insert `sys.path.insert(0,"..")` and use the `importlib` which worked for me. But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6466139/3786108), using sys.path is a dirty way to do this. I will try to do the mentioned `setuptools` method. Although I don't know why there is so much of a hassle to just get a package from parent directory. where in other languages it is kind of easy.