# How to source a .py script that resides in a folder starting with a digit? - SOLUTION POSTED AT BOTTOM

Tags: python, escaping, python-import, naming-conventions, importerror

## SOLUTION POSTED AT BOTTOM

Thanks to the commentators for pointing me in the right direction. Between their help and [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430372/how-do-i-get-the-full-path-of-the-current-files-directory) I was able to come to a robust solution which is posted at the bottom.

## Situation

I have a .py script called `job.py` that relies on data in another .py script called `data.py`. Both scripts reside in the same folder, `05_scripts`. The `05_scripts` folder sits under Git version control in a parent folder called `project`.

Thus, the complete paths to the two scripts are:
`project/05_scripts/job.py` and
`project/05_scripts/data.py`.

## Problem: I cannot import `data.py` without renaming the folder `05_scripts`.

In `job.py` I want to source the `data.py` file. This is problematic because the `data.py` file sits in a folder whose name begins with a digit, `05_scripts/`. *If* I change the folder name to `_05_scripts/` or something else so that the first character is non-numeric, then I achieve my goal and import the `data.py` script without a problem. However, *this is unacceptable* since this is part of a much larger project and it is not acceptable to change all references to this folder.

## What an acceptable solution must look like

The solution I need is code in `job.py` that can successfully import `data.py` *without* renaming the `05_scripts/` folder.

### What I have tried

#### Attempt 1

Input:

```
from 05_scripts.data import *
```

Output:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from 05_scripts.data import *
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

#### Attempt 2

Input:

```
from '05_scripts'.data import *
```

Output:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from '05_scripts'.data import *
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

#### Attempt 3

Input:

```
from '05_scripts.data' import *
```

Output:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from '05_scripts.data' import *
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

#### Attempt 4

Input:

```
from data import *
```

Output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'
```

#### Attempt 5

Input:

```
import data
```

Output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'
```

#### Other attempts

I also tried variations of the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number). This included different variations of using `__import__` and `importlib.import_module()` but *could not* get a working solution that did not include renaming the parent folder.

### Recall, this works but is not an acceptable solution for my use case:

After renaming `05_scripts/` to `_05_scripts`,

Input:

```
from _05_scripts.data import *
```

## SOLUTION

```
# Getting the path for the project and doing string manipulation.
import os
import re
working_dir = re.sub("\\\\", "/", os.getcwd())
scripts_dir = working_dir + "/05_scripts"

# Importing all from the data.py script
import site
site.addsitedir(scripts_dir)
from data import *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import sys
syspath_05scripts = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "05_scripts")
sys.path.insert(0, syspath_05scripts)

import something_from_05
```

Comment: Does not work: sys.path.insert("<path to script>/05_scripts")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: sys.path.insert(0, "path_to/05_scripts")  # :-D

Comment: This gets me 90% to where I want to be, :).
How do I make the path relative to the project folder? Project folders may move, so I want to be able to have the sys.path.insert(0, "<path to project>/05_scripts") robust enough to handle when project folders move.

Also, `import data` does not work. However, `from data import *` does work.

Comment: You can use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get the path to the directory where your script resides. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I already posted a solution that is robust and covers my need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `site` package to add custom locations to be included to for module search path

```
>>> import site
>>> site.addsitedir('05_scripts')
>>> import data
>>> data
<module 'data' from '<removed>/05_scripts/data.py'>
```

Comment: You need to create a empty `__init__.py` file under 05_scripts. Do `touch path/05_scripts/__init__.py` and try again

Comment: I had a mistake in my code (the file is not really called `data.py` in my real example). Removing previous comments now.

Comment: `/opt` was just the full path to the directory. I have now updated the answer for relative path. Go to the directory where you `05_scripts`, start a python shell and it would work

Comment: Similar to the proposed solution by krimeo, this gets me 90% of the way to where I want to be if I use `from data import *` instead of `import data`. However, how do I make this more robust in case the project folder moves (as it will)? I do not want to hardcode the path since the project folder is bound to move.

Comment: I posted a solution that is robust and covers my need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a folder structure like this the following code should work for you.

```
project/main.py
project/05_scripts/
project/05_scripts/__init__.py
project/05_scripts/job.py
project/05_scripts/data.py
```

project/05_scripts/data.py

```py
what_i_want_to_get = {'hello': 'there'}
```

project/main.py

```py
from importlib import import_module

# this is the same as calling "import 05_scripts.data as data"
data = import_module('05_scripts.data')

print(data.what_i_want_to_get)

# this should print {'hello': 'there'}
```

Comment: Does not work: data = getattr(import_module('05_scripts'), 'data') 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module '05_scripts' has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Jayden, could you perhaps share what what 05_scripts/ contents are? Does it contain an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: The error persists with or without the presence of `init.py`,`_init_.py` or `__init__.py` files in the 05_scripts/ folder.
The contents of the folder are somewhat sensitive, so I cannot share details. However, I just need a solution that can generalize for how to get the `job.py` file to source the `data.py` file when they reside together in a folder with a name that begins with a digit.

Comment: Jayden please see my revised answer, I tried the above on my end and I believe this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but the purpose is to source `data.py` using `job.py`, not `main.py`.  I do not have any program called `main.py`. In fact, the main programming language in the parent folder is not Python in this project, but another language which calls `job.py`.

Comment: Got it, that's what was missing. I should had specifically asked about your entrypoint.  Are you certain that `from data import *` at the top of your `job.py` isn't working for you? I tried it on my end and was able to `print(what_i_want_to_get)`

Comment: I posted a solution that is robust and covers my needs. Thank you!