# How do you import a module with its name starting with '#'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I shall inform you that this is my first question on stack overflow, so if I did any mistakes then tell me. I am a 15 year old teenager learning Python.
Now coming to the point. I have named all my files as `#1 detail_detail`, `#2 detail_detail`.

Now my instructor has introduced me to modules but when I import my files it comes as a comment.

```
from #33 modules_part_2 import *
```

Plz help me.

Comment: # is a python keyword and you can't use it in your module names. Simply rename your files and then import them

Comment: I don't think that is a valid module name. Not sure about module names, but python variables can only start with a letter, and apart from letters, can only contain underscores (`_`) and spaces.

Comment: There is a workaround described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090079/in-python-how-to-import-filename-starts-with-a-number) that would work in this situation. However, I'd **strongly advise against this**. The best actionable advice would be to **rename your files to something more appropriate**.

Comment: Read the doc: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#:~:text=Modules%20should%20have%20short%2C%20all,use%20of%20underscores%20is%20discouraged.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no effort from OP.

Comment: Also, he introduced you to modules before he teached you to use comments? Pretty sure you understand what's wrong as soon as you read this tid-bit about [Inline Comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments)

Answer (score 2):

Use [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module):

```
import importlib
your_module = importlib.import_module("#1 detail_detail")
```

It's still not advised to have this kind of naming convention for your modules in Python.